# Is there any way to check whether the interrupt is handled or not?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling, keyboardinterrupt

Suppose my CPU is hogged down and I want to check whether any coming interrupt from any hardware device is handled or not? 
eg: on pressing keyboard CPU is giving no response, then I want to know whether processor handled my keyboard interrupt or not. Is there any interface to check.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard handler itself is often a good interface to determine if the system is live. In the default mode, the tty line discipline will echo characters typed at the keyboard (this echoing is done by the kernel and isn't dependent on any user-space process getting scheduled). So if you're sitting at an idle command line on the system console, and you're not seeing the characters you typed echo onto the screen, there's a good chance your system is locked up. Note, however, that the mode can be changed by a program (such as vi/vim) and that can turn this echoing off (in that case you only see what the vim process prints to the screen).

A second test is to access the machine from the network. There are several things that should cause responses when sent from another machine. If you send a ping (an ICMP Echo Request), the kernel should automatically respond with an ICMP Echo Reply packet. Or if you know there's a server running on port 5000 (say), you should be able to create a connection to that port even if the server process itself never gets a chance to run (the TCP SYN-ACK sent in response to the SYN is done completely within the kernel). If these work, you know network interrupts are being processed, and the kernel's network soft-interrupt handler is being scheduled.

There are other things that would show you whether the keyboard interrupt is triggering and being handled, but those would generally require you to have a *working* command line link to the machine.

If you have such a link, `cat /proc/interrupts` will show you counts for each interrupt for each CPU. If the keyboard is interrupting, for example, one of those counts should increase on each interrupt.

You should never have a case where an interrupt is occurring but is not being serviced. All interrupts will be serviced before user-space processing is resumed. (Exactly what it means to service the interrupt is up to the driver and may vary by device / device type.)

If no interrupts are being serviced at all, your system will be completely locked up and unusable as no input or output at all will generally occur without interrupts.

Comment: My question is general for all the interrupts, I want to know if the interrupt is handled or not if the CPU is 100% loaded. As you know that as soon as interrupt comes context switching happens but in my case since the CPU load is 100% or suppose CPU is not able to process interrupt somehow . Is there any way we can manually trigger the interrupt, any interface from which we can see that interrupt controller has recieved the interrupt but CPU is unable to process it and call interrupt handler

Comment: When you say "the CPU is 100% loaded", this implies that there is a backlog of runnable *user processes* at all times. However, interrupts always take precedence over user processes, so they will still be handled. If interrupt handlers *themselves* fail to complete (or fail to allow other interrupts) then other handlers could be blocked from running. This is either a bug in a device driver or a system design problem. There's no convenient interface to view or troubleshoot such a condition.

Comment: I know that interrupt takes precedence over user space process but I am not able to get how context switching happens if CPU is 100% loaded, that is CPU is in hanged stage.

Comment: 100% loaded does *not* mean that the CPU is hung. It just means that it's busy and is "fully stocked" with processes that want to run. It's a normal state and requires no recovery. If it's hung, OTOH, that generally means that (a) interrupts are disabled and it is executing instructions that will never re-enable them ("off in the weeds"), or (b) the processor has actually entered a "shutdown" state (say, due to an exception while attempting to invoke an exception handler). These latter conditions generally require a reset or power cycle to recover from.